# Make text appear on hover using CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to show specific text on hover, while the other text should hide. I have the text hiding during hover and the animation correct, but I cannot get the other text to appear on hover. Ideally this text will filled the entire scaled box. What am I missing to have the text appear in the div `data-hover`?

```css
.process-section {
  margin: 20px auto 20px auto;
  padding: 50px 30px 30px 30px;
  background: rgb(223, 232, 236);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px #737373;
  max-width: 1000px;
}
.container{
  display: flex;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: #3a5f77;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  transition: 0.25s ease;
}
.container div{
  line-height: 2;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.data-no-hover:hover{
  opacity: 0;
}
.container:hover{
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
.data-hover{
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
}
.data-hover:hover{
  display: flex;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0.8;
  transform: scale(2);
}
```

```html
<section class="process-section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="data-no-hover">
      <p>Text to display when not hovering</p>
    </div>
    <div class="data-hover">
      <p>Text to display when hovering</p>
    </div>
  </div> 
</section>
```

Comment: add a `z-index` value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `display:none` element have no size (width: 0, height: 0) - you therefore can't "hover" element like that.

Try using child selectors for example, like:

```css
/* When normal state */
.container > .data-no-hover { opacity: 1; }
.container > .data-hover { opacity: 0; }
/* When mouse over container */
.container:hover > .data-no-hover { opacity: 0; }
.container:hover > .data-hover { opacity: 1; }
```

Also when you're thinking about animation, remove `display` property completely, because it's not "animable" - it will always hard break.

CSS selectors are pretty clever, if you're not looking for old browser support, you can also use *:not* pseudoclass `.data-hover:not(:hover)`

References:

- [Display not animbale](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)
- [CSS direct child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator)
- [CSS :not pseudoclass](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)